# Countdown Timer (JS)

Tags: javascript

I currently use this to count down every hour, but I want to countdown to every 15 minutes, how would i do it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getMinutesUntilNextHour() {
    return 60 - new Date().getMinutes();
  }
  document.write(getMinutesUntilNextHour());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   return 15 - new Date().getMinutes()%15;
```

gives you how many minutes there is to the next quarter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getMinutesUntilNextHour() { 
    return 15 - (new Date().getMinutes()% 15);
}
```

Comment: And change the name of the function xD